# Showing $\inf A=0$, for $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{\frac{1}{n}\}\subset(0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this problem given to me from my intro. to analysis course I was  hoping you guys could help me with. Obviously, there's something I'm not  understanding, so I appreciate any hints/suggestions. Thanks in advance.

---

I claim that $\inf A=0$, so I need to find $a\in A$ such that $a<0+\epsilon,\forall\epsilon>0$. I thought of $a=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\in A$, but $\frac{1}{\epsilon}<\epsilon$ doesn't hold for epsilon less than one. I also thought of of $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, but $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}\implies n=\frac{2}{\epsilon}\not\in [1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is $a=\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$, which is true if you choose $n > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: So one would be $n=1+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon+1}<\epsilon\implies\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}<1$, right?

Comment: @AlexD No. In most cases, $\varepsilon$ is not the inverse of a natural number. What you need is that $n > 1/\varepsilon$ (and it can be any such $n$, however large), and it will follow that $a=1/n \in A$ is such that $a < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of your $a$ as a variable. Instead think of it as a function:

You're looking for a function $a(\epsilon)$, so that $\frac{1}{a(\epsilon)} <\epsilon$ .

Now all that's left to do is manipulate the equation so that $a(\epsilon)$ is isolated on one side:
$$\frac{1}{a(\epsilon)} <\epsilon \Leftrightarrow a(\epsilon) >\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

And then choose your function $a(\epsilon)$ so that it fulfills the inequality.